# mysqlnd_ms error - getaddrinfo failed, mysqlnd_global_stats in Unknown

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, mysqli, ec2-ami, mysqlnd

I'm trying to set up mysqlnd_ms so that it serves its purpose of doing the reads on the slave db and writes on the master db. However, I'm getting this error when httpd is restarted.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_ms.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_ms.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_global_stats in Unknown on line 0
```

I'm running an Amazon EC2 x64 AMI instance and ran the following commands on a fresh instance:

```
sudo yum update

sudo yum install -y gcc make gcc-c++

sudo yum install -y httpd24 php54

sudo yum install -y php54-devel php54-mysqlnd php54-mbstring

sudo pecl install mysqlnd_ms

php -m | grep mysql
```

My php.ini included the following additions:

```
mysqlnd_ms.enable=1
mysqlnd_ms.force_config_usage=1
mysqlnd_ms.config_file=/etc/mysqlnd_ms.ini
extension=mysqlnd_ms.so
```

The mysqlnd_ms.ini file has this:

```
{    
"appname": {
    "master": {
        "master_0": {
            "host": "1.2.3.4",
            "db": "dbname",
            "user": "dbuser",
            "password": "dbpswd",
            "socket" : "\/var\/lib\/mysql\/mysql.sock"
        }
    },
    "slave": {
        "slave_0": {
            "host": "12.22.32.42",
            "db": "dbname",
            "user": "dbuser",
            "password": "dbpswd",
            "socket" : "\/var\/lib\/mysql\/mysql.sock"
        }
       }
}
}
```

To connect, I do:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("appname", "dbuser", "dbpswd", "schema");
```

Doing the above throws the following error:

```
ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

Mysqli, mysql, and pdo are all enabled on the server.

If we change it directly to the host name, it works:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("1.2.3.4", "dbuser", "dbpswd", "schema");
```

How can I get mysqlnd_ms to function properly?

Comment: has `appname` been registered with the dns system, or at least with the server's `hosts` file? if not,then there's no way for the server to translate `appname` -> `1.2.3.4`.

Comment: No, cause that would defeat the purpose of the mysqlnd_ms set up. The way it is supposed to work is that the code refers to the "appname" and mysqlnd_ms then hooks on to its own config file to pick a master or slave server for the "appname" (based on the sql query). Check an example: http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-ms.quickstart.usage.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Problem solved!!!*

To resolve this issue:

1. Remove the lines:

> mysqlnd_ms.enable=1
>
> mysqlnd_ms.force_config_usage=1
>
> mysqlnd_ms.config_file=/etc/mysqlnd_ms_cfg.ini
>
> extension=mysqlnd_ms.so

from the php.ini file

1. Create a new file called "/etc/php.d/mysqlnd_ms.ini" and put those lines in there
2. Reload httpd