# Required (included) mysql connect script working in one script but not in another. PHP

Tags: php, database, mysqli, database-connection

I have an extended login class which extends the standard mysqli class in php
which is the following:

```
<?php
require_once("Config.php");

define(MYSQL_HOST, "host");
define(MYSQL_USER, "user");
define(MYSQL_PW, "password");
define(MYSQL_DB, "db");

/**
 * MysqlDB default wrapper, extend this if more specific needs are meant. Contains some helper functions for Select, Insert and Update.
 * @author Jerrpan
 * @version 1
 *
 */

class DB extends mysqli
{
    /**
     * Connects to db specified in Config.php file
     * @throws MysqlConnectError
     *      On failed connection
     */
    function __Construct() {
        parent::__construct(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PW, MYSQL_DB);
        if($this->connect_error) { 
            throw new MysqlConnectError($this->connect_error); }
    }

    /**
     * Finds out if db is up or not
     */

    private function isCon() {
        return $this->ping();
    }

    /**
     * Executes an Select statment
     * @param Assoc Array $data
     *      Array(
     *              "column"    => "column1, column2",
     *              "table"     => "table1, table2",
     *              "where"     => "column1 = value",
     *              "join"      => "INNERJOIN table ON column1 = column2",
     *              "orderby"   => "id DESC",
     *              "limit"     => 100
     *          )
     * @throws MysqlConnectError
     *      On lost mysql connection
     * @throws MysqlInvalidQuery
     *      On invalid query
     * @return void|stmt()
     *      On success an stmt object for further useage like storing and fetching.
     */

    public function Select($data) {
        if(!$this->isCon()) { throw new MysqlConnectError("Connection shut down"); }

        foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            if($value{0} == ",") { throw new MysqlInvalidQuery("Start or stop char cant be ,"); }
            if($value{strlen($value)} == ",") { throw new MysqlInvalidQuery("Start or stop char cant be ,"); }
        }

        if(isset($data["column"])) {
            $column = " SELECT {$data["column"]} "; 
        } else {
            throw new MysqlInvalidQuery("You have to specify columns");
        }

        if(isset($data["table"])) {
            $table = " FROM {$data["table"]} ";
        } else {
            throw new MysqlInvalidQuery("You have to specify tables");
        }

        if(isset($data["where"])) {
            $where = " WHERE {$data["where"]} ";
        }

        if(isset($data["join"])) {
            $innerjoin = " {$data["innerjoin"]} ";
        }

        if(isset($data["orderby"])) {
            $orderby = " {$data["orderby"]} ";
        }

        if(isset($data["limit"])) {
            $limit = " LIMIT {$data["limit"]} ";
        }

        $stmt = $this->query("$column $table $where $innerjoin $orderby $limit");
        if(!$stmt) { throw new MysqlInvalidQuery("Invalid query"); return;}
        return $stmt;
    }

    /**
     * Executes an insert statement
     * @param String $table
     *      The table to insert data into, can only be one
     * @param Assoc Array $data
     *      The data to insert as Colum => Value
     * @throws MysqlConnectError
     *      On lost db connection
     * @throws MysqlInvalidQuery
     *      On invalid query
     * @return boolean|void
     *      True on success
     */
    public function Insert($table, $data) { 
        $ins_table;
        $ins_value;

        if(!$this->isCon()) { throw new MysqlConnectError("Connection shut down"); }
        if(strstr($table, ",") != false) { throw new MysqlInvalidQuery("Several tables cant be inserted in one query"); }

        foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            $ins_table .= "$key,";
            $ins_value .= "$value,";
        }
            $ins_table = substr($ins_table, 0, -1);
            $ins_value = substr($ins_value, 0, -1);

        $this->query("INSERT INTO $table($ins_table) VALUES($ins_value)");
        if($this->affected_rows == 1) { return true; } else { throw new MysqlInvalidQuery("Invalid query"); }
    }

    /**
     * Executes an update statement
     * @param String $table
     *      The table to update, can not be more than one
     * @param Assoc Array $data
     *      The data to update the rows with in the context Column => Value
     * @param String $where
     *      The where statement without the WHERE
     * @param number $limit
     *      The limit, the default limit is 100
     * @throws MysqlConnectError
     *      On lost connection
     * @throws MysqlInvalidQuery
     *      On an invalid query
     * @return boolean|void
     *      On success true, on no affected rows false
     */
    public function Update($table, $data, $where, $limit = 100) {
        $ins;

        if(!$this->isCon()) { throw new MysqlConnectError("Connection shut down"); }

        foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            $ins .= " $key = $value , ";
        }
            $ins = substr($ins, 0, -2);

        $stmt = $this->query("UPDATE $table SET $ins WHERE $where LIMIT $limit" );
        if(!$stmt) { throw new MysqlInvalidQuery("Invalid query"); }
        if($this->affected_rows > 0) { return true; }

        return false;
    }
}

class MysqlConnectError     extends Exception {}
class MysqlInvalidQuery     extends Exception {}
```

Which is then used by adding `require_once('path/to/mysqlclass.php')` to another script and create a new object of DB().

And so long everything is working fine. However when I try to 
`require_once('../path/to/mysqlpath.php)` (notice ../)

I get the following error:

> mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in etc...

I am completely struck with this, so what is the cause of this problem
  and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795500/mysqlnd-ms-error-getaddrinfo-failed-mysqlnd-global-stats-in-unknown

Comment: Not to shabby answer but I do not have access to the php ini files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you `require_once('../path/to/mysqlpath.php)` please check the content of 
`MYSQL_HOST`.

In general the error `php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed` means, 
that your server is unable to resolve the domain name example.com to an ip address.
So either the dns server is unreachable or there's a misconfiguration in your webserver's dns client or the HOST name is wrong.

Comment: I tested the content MYSQL_HOST. MYSQL_HOST become undefined. Actually the constants and mysql extended class was in different scripts which caused the definitions from not being loaded before the construction of class DB. So I will solve this either by using a separate require script or somehow prevent anything from being executed unil the constants has been loaded.

Comment: I solved it by just adding the constants to the class script. Now works like charm. Thank you